# Problem with facebook login using passport (Node.js Express)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am following the code examples from the book "Node.js 8 the right way" by Jim R. Wilson.

In the book you are building a small application that allows you to sign in through Facebook (Using Passport.js)

Here is my code for setting up Passport middleware:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const FaceBookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new FaceBookStrategy({
  clientID: nconf.get('auth:facebook:appID'),
  clientSecret: nconf.get('auth:facebook:appSecret'),
  callbackURL: new URL('/auth/facebook/callback', serviceUrl).href
},
    (accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done) => done(null,profile)
));

app.get('/auth/facebook',passport.authenticate('facebook'));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/'
}));
```

However when I try logging in, Facebook responds by saying that it only accepts logins from a safe site (https). Has something changed since this book was written, or do i need to set up my server to use https in order to use Facebook login?

Comment: probably, recommended yes.

Comment: Yes, the Facebook policies require the use of https.

[Related_ISSUE](https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/510)